# Adding imported icons to TabBarIOS.Item

Tags: reactjs, tabs, icons, react-native, tabbar

I am trying to incorporate FontAwesome icons into my React-Native TabBarIOS, but I cannot seem to figure out how.  Does anybody know a way to do this?  Here is an example of one of my TabBarIOS.Items:

```
<TabBarIOS.Item
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'searchTab'}
      title={'Search Books'}
      onPress={() => this.navigateToTab('searchTab')}>
      <SearchView/>
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to achieve this.

Install the package: `npm install --save react-native-vector-icons`

On your component page import the plugin `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';`

Your TabbarIos component:

```
<TabBarIOS>
      <Icon.TabBarItem
        title="Search Books"
        iconName="fa-search"
        selectedIconName="fa-search"
        >
        <View style={styles.searchStyle}><Text>Search Books ...</Text></View>
      </Icon.TabBarItem>
</TabBarIOS>
```

If you don't want to use 3rd party plugins, [react-native TabBarIos](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html) has an example.

You'll first have to convert icon image into base64. This [online tool](http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/) should help/

`var base64Icon = 'data:image/png;base64,.........';`

```
<TabBarIOS.Item
      title="Blue Tab"
      icon={{uri: base64Icon, scale: 3}}  //here
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'blueTab'}
      onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
          selectedTab: 'blueTab',
        });
      }}>
      {this._renderContent('#414A8C', 'Blue Tab')}
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Comment: Yes, I figured this out and tried to post the answer, I guess it didn't go through, thank you though.